# Make a non symmetrical confusion matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have a df with the columns: Site, True and Predicted. This has n samples from 4 sites (A, B, C, D), so 4n samples in total. Each site is either one of two classes (Sites A&B are class High, Sites C&D are class Low). Here are what the first 4 rows of my dataframe look like:

| Site | Label | Prediction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | High | Low |
| B | High | High |
| C | Low | Low |
| D | Low | Low |
| ... | ... | ... |

Instead of the normal 2x2 confusion matrix this can be used to generate, for example with 40 samples:

| class | High | Low |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low | 11 | 9 |
| High | 9 | 11 |

I want to create a 4x2 one, so I can see which sites are getting missclassified as high or low, so it would look something like this (using 10 samples from each site):

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Low | 8 | 9 | 3 | 0 |
| High | 2 | 1 | 7 | 10 |

How can this be done? I would like it as a numpy matrix

Here's a longer screenshot of the csv, this has n samples:[image]

Comment: Can you explain the `8,9, 5, 10` in the first row?

Comment: Is this a `crosstab`? `pd.crosstab(df['Prediction'], df['Site'])`

Comment: @QuangHoang in this example I have ten samples from each site, and a model has predicted whether they are of the High or Low class.

Comment: The thing is it doesn't go with your sample data, so people wouldn't know how to help you.

Comment: @mozway if I understand correctly, this is what the confusion matrix would normally look like, but I want to create the 4x2 not a 2x2 matrix

Comment: Give it a try, you will have a 4x2

Comment: Have tried but it gives a 2x2! Would I not need to use the 'Site' column somewhere in that line?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can the `Label` of the site `HighA` be `Low`?  Can you share the full data set?  Maybe just add a block of CSV text to the question, or provide a link to a data file.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I've clarified detail and added this to hopefully make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly and you like to know the misspecified labels in each category for each site. If this is the case, then the following code might answer your question.

```
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

# Recreate data table
InputTable = {'Site': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],\
        'Label': ['High', 'High', 'Low', 'Low','High', 'High', 'Low', 'Low','High', 'High', 'Low', 'Low'],\
        'Predicted': ['Low', 'High', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'High', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'High', 'Low', 'Low']}
df = pd.DataFrame(InputTable)

# Overview
SiteList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
Levels = ['Low', 'High']

# Preallocate
Result = np.empty((len(Levels), len(SiteList))); Result[:] = np.NaN

# Compute entries
for iter1 in range(len(Levels)):
    for iter2 in range(len(SiteList)):

        # Current selection
        SelectedLevel = Levels[iter1]
        SelectedSite= SiteList[iter2]

        # A misclassified level X has predicted label X and true label unequal to X
        Result[iter1, iter2] = len(df[ (df['Site'] == SelectedSite) & (df['Label'] != SelectedLevel) & (df['Predicted'] == SelectedLevel) ])

# Print result
print('\n')
print( tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql', showindex=True) )
print('\n')
print(pd.DataFrame(Result, index=Levels, columns=SiteList))
```

The result is

```
        A    B    C    D
Low   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
High  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

which is correct given that 3 predicted Low's are misspecified (only at Site A).